# Word document: line spacing

Tags: microsoft-word, layout

In a word document, I want it such that if two lines are present with some space between them, when I press enter the space shouldn't be changed

For example, two lines like:

> Q1: What is your name?
>   Q2: Are you on time?

The space between the Q1: and Q2: lines shouldn't be changed if someone presses enter with the cursor between the two of the lines.

What should I do?

Comment: That was a frankly astounding number of grammatical errors for a single post. There should be a badge for that

Comment: So you want the lines to be static and uneditable?

Comment: your SO question was migrated here earlier.  please don't crosspost in the future. hang on, will find and merge. [edit: merge complete.]

Comment: yes i want lines to be static and uneditable

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to create a form for people to fill out, then print or email back.

You might want to look at [how to create a form in Microsoft Word](http://www.officearticles.com/word/create_a_fill-in_form_in_microsoft_word.htm).  You can add text entry fields that users can type into.  You can restrict the text fields so they are only single lines rather than accepting multiple lines.  You also can be sure that typing too much text into the form fields won't ruin the layout of the document, and protect the document so users can't type into the wrong places.

A second option would be to [create a form as a PDF file](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat/solutions/detail/create_form.html).  This way, even users without Microsoft Word can view and complete your form.

Comment: yes kind of form only i want to generate.